# Formulários de pesquisa

Tags: html

Existe alguma forma de enviar dados de um campo do meu formulário html por exemplo tenho uma página html com um formulário simples campo Nome do autor e o outro campo título  do livro e um botão pesquisar, gostaria que quando eu digitasse no campo Nome e clicasse em pesquisar esse dado digitado fosse direcionado para página do Google por exemplo e fizesse a pesquisa como se eu tivesse digitado na página do Google esse termo e clicado em pesquisar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você criar um formulário com a `action` para `https://google.com/search` como o método `GET` e nomear o seu campo de busca como `q`.

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Leandro Angelo, muito obrigado pela sua resposta esta bem detalhada, era exatamente isso que queria, porem gostaria de fazer isso nessa pagina de uma biblioteca:

http://www.biblioteca.pucpr.br/pergamum/biblioteca/index.php?_ga=2.15085749.209816061.1540919329-1079188922.1499789354

Pelo que estava vendo não tem como fazer sem ter acesso ao código fonte da pagina né ?

Att
Adriano

Comment: @adrianoeurich Nesse caso é uma pergunta completamente diferente da que foi postada. E no caso específico seria mais interessante você entrar em contato com a Pucpr e verificar se eles disponibilizam algum serviço ou api para pesquisa ao seu acervo.

Comment: Entendi, ok, muito obrigado pela atenção e pelas respostas!